# Is this a good way to measure percentage of total available memory used?

Tags: memory

I'd like to know how much I'm using of the total memory Mathematica has available but I've found no built in function that would tell me this, so I've came up with this pretty straightforward formula:

```
MemoryInUse[]/(MemoryInUse[] + MemoryAvailable[])
```

Is this a proper way to do this?

Comment: Hm. No. `MemoryAvailable[]` counts only available RAM while `MemoryInUse[]` does also count memory in swap. So `MemoryInUse[]` can be higher that the size of RAM, but your formula cannot reflect that.

Comment: I see. Do you maybe have a suggestion that would work better?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. There might be a good reason why the functionality you are looking for has not been implemented.